# iOS app - delete buttons not showing when table view is in editing mode

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am very new to iOS but I've created a view controller with a table view which i want to put into editing mode. This is my view controller implementation file code:

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController
@synthesize progsTable, programmes;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    programmes = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"one",@"two",@"three",nil];
    //set the title
    self.title = @"Programmes";

    //add an edit button
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (void)setEditing:(BOOL)editing animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super setEditing:editing animated:animated];
    [progsTable setEditing:editing animated:animated];
}

#pragma mark - UITableView Datasource

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return programmes.count;
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

    if(cell==nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = [programmes objectAtIndex: indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}

- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *) indexPath {
    return YES;
}
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (editingStyle==UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        //remove from array
        [programmes removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        //remove from table
        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    }
}
#pragma mark - UITableView Delegate methods

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

}

@end
```

I get the edit button in the top left but when i click it the red delete buttons don't appear - what am I doing wrong?

Comment: incidentally it's based on this tutorial http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NHzm-D9VsQA - i think i've followed his instructions exactly but it's not working for me. i'm using xcode 5 with storyboards, whereas this tutorial uses xib files - could that be the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Running your exact code does work - the delete buttons are displaying when i test it.

I believe the problem is that you haven't assigned your @property called progsTable to your Table View.

To solve it do the following:

- Go to your Storyboard
- Right click on your View Controller
- Click and hold the + next to the outlet called progsTable while you drag the mouse to your Table View, like this:

[image]

Try running your app - the delete buttons should now appear.

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to add the code below:

```
- (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
return UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete; }
```

This tells the UITableView which editing style you want.

Answer (score 1):

Use this

```
- (IBAction)deleteDrug:(id)sender event:(id)event {
    selectedButtonIndex = [self indexPathForButton:sender event:event];

    [tableView setEditing:YES animated:YES];
}


- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (indexPath == selectedButtonIndex) {
        return YES;
    }

    return NO;
}
```

You may need to implement this method for your datasource.

```
- (UITableViewCellEditingStyle) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check that you also have auto-layout constraints added in interface builder so that the very end of the cell lines up with the width of your device.

Run the code on the ipad in the simulator, if the delete button shows up there but not  on the iphone simulator then it probably just that the contents are not aligned properly to the viewport of your device.

My 'delete' button was not showing up but the cell title content were moving over to the left when I swiped, however I had not set constraints on my cell width in my storyboard, as soon as I set the right-edge constraint to '0' or '16', the delete button appeared.